# Possible subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Which is the possible subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^2$

1. Any line passing through $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$
2. Any line passing through $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T$

It is given that the answer is option 2, but I am unable to get that. Can someone help?

Comment: A subspace must contain the neutral element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line passing through $(1,1)$ may not include the origin; that line is not a vector space by way of not including the origin. A line passing through $(0,0)$ is a vector space; it may be written as $\{rx:r\in\mathbb R\}$ for some nonzero vector $x$.